# how do I speed up a bundle install?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

Sometimes I have to run bundle install 10 times in an hour just to the right gems. Presumably this bit:

Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/

Is only necessary periodically, but definitely doesn't need to be done 10 times in one hour, right? Is there any way to skip this, and use a local cache?

Any help appreciated. Seriously bogging me down...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid updating sources:

`gem install my_gem --no-update-sources`

You could setup a local gem repository, and specify local file paths for your gems in Gemfile.

`gem 'my_gem', '1.0.0', :path => '/path/to/my_gem'`

You could also set up a [local rubygems server](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/18), which could be used through:

`source 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' # your gem server`

Comment: Yeah, forgot about that. `--local` requires setting up a local gem repository, but, yes, that will help, too.